# Android shared element transition not working with different img scale types

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation

I want to perform shared element transition when switching from Activity A to Activity B. The problem is that transition animation is not working smoothly when shared imageViews **scale types are different**. I am noticing a "bounce" in the very beginning of transition (on not animated imageView scaleType change I guess). The same "bounce" I am noticing when coming back from Activity B to Activity A.

Details:

Activity A contains imageView with **scaleType: centerCrop**. 
Actvity B contains imageView with **scaleType: fitXY**.

Both ImageView have `android:transitionName="sharedView"`, of course.

My transition set in xml looks like this:

```
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <changeBounds/>
   <changeImageTransform/>
</transitionSet>
```

In documentation about this config is written:

> In combination with ChangeBounds, ChangeImageTransform allows
>   ImageViews that change size, shape, or **ImageView.ScaleType** to animate
>   contents smoothly.

So why my transition is not working smoothly? Or how to animate scaleType change during shared element transition if `changeBounds` with `changeImageTransform` doesn't seem to work?

Worth to mention that if I make scale types equal (e.g. centerCrop and centerCrop) of shared views - then transition works smoothly and everything is ok.

Comment: did you ever find a fix for this?

Comment: No. still looking forward for answers/suggestions.

Comment: Can you share a little more of your code? Are you using an image loading library like Picasso or Glide? I've recently spent many hours on this, but I think I finally have it where it is reasonable. It will never be perfect though.

Comment: If you found something which works for you, would you mind sharing your solution?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem in my case. Here is something you need to check:

- Make sure your Shared element is `ImageView` for both source and target activity (Don't use any container).
- Set the `transitionName` for the ImageView (not its container).

After I updated this, `changeImageTransform` will do its job changing scaleType smoothly between 2 `ImageView`s

Answer (score -2):

Had same problem. Solved it by setting same `padding` property for both `ImageView`'s. I don't know why it works so, but hope it can help someone.